# Display output of process in php

Tags: php, linux, process, rsync

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");

// tell php to automatically flush after every output
// including lines of output produced by shell commands
disable_ob();

$command = 'sudo rsync -arz --progress /home/lokesh/Desktop /home/lokesh/Downloads --stats';
system($command);

function disable_ob() {
    // Turn off output buffering
    ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
    // Turn off PHP output compression
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);
    // Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
    //ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    // Clear, and turn off output buffering
    while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
        // Get the curent level
        $level = ob_get_level();
        // End the buffering
        ob_end_clean();        
        // If the current level has not changed, abort
        if (ob_get_level() == $level) break;
    }
    // Disable apache output buffering/compression
    if (function_exists('apache_setenv')) {
        apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');
        apache_setenv('dont-vary', '1');
    }
}
```

**above my code gives me output like this.**

**OUTPUT**

Desktop/
Desktop/CloudRDP.bat

```
        336 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00  
        336 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, ir-chk=1055/1057)
```

Desktop/Days of the Week Song - 7 Days of the Week - Children's Songs by The Learning Station.mp4

```
     32,768   0%  888.89kB/s    0:00:22  
  5,308,416  27%    5.06MB/s    0:00:02  
  5,636,096  28%    2.41MB/s    0:00:05  
 10,846,208  55%    3.20MB/s    0:00:02  
 15,826,944  80%    3.56MB/s    0:00:01  
 19,611,127 100%    3.75MB/s    0:00:04 (xfr#2, ir-chk=1054/1057)
```

Desktop/EnjayEsync Ver 2.4.1.rar

```
     32,768   1%   42.61kB/s    0:00:49  
  1,277,952  59%    1.22MB/s    0:00:00  
  2,135,855 100%    1.73MB/s    0:00:01 (xfr#3, ir-chk=1053/1057)
```

Desktop/EnjayOnlineProductRegistration.sql

```
     32,768  13%  181.82kB/s    0:00:01  
    235,670 100%    1.05MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#4, ir-chk=1052/1057)
```

But I want to count number of file transfer by searching "**xfr#**" string. How this is possible. I have tried to loop but unable to do this. Means  after get this string (**xfr#4**) it show me output 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you need not only the last line of the command's output, then instead of [system — Execute an external program and display the output —](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) use [popen — Opens process file pointer —](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) (to read line by line) or [exec — Execute an external program](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) (to get an array filled with every line of output).